# Imprimir valor en un input text

Tags: javascript, html

Quisiera imprimir el resultado de la siguiente función en un input text es posible,ya que solo lo puedo imprimir en un div ,span ,p.

```
 function getManufacturerInfo()
    {var dfd = new $.Deferred();
       oxpddiscovery.GetOXPdDiscoveryTree()
       .then(function(discoveryTree){
        try
        { oxpddeviceinfo.Setup(discoveryTree);
            oxpddeviceinfo.GetManufacturerInfo()
                .then(function(deviceinfo)
                {
                    try
                    {   oxpddeviceinfo.GetManufacturerInfo();
                        dfd.resolve(); 
                        document.getElementById("SerialNumber").innerHTML = deviceinfo.deviceSerialNumber;
                        document.getElementById("hostName").innerHTML = deviceinfo.hostName;
                        document.getElementById("firmwareVersion").innerHTML = deviceinfo.firmwareVersion; 
                        document.getElementById("productNumber").innerHTML = deviceinfo.productNumber;
                        document.getElementById("ipAddress").innerHTML = deviceinfo.ipAddress;
                        document.getElementById("macAddress").innerHTML = deviceinfo.macAddress;
                        document.getElementById("deviceId").innerHTML = deviceinfo.deviceId;
                        document.getElementById("formatterSerialNumber").innerHTML = deviceinfo.formatterSerialNumber;
                    }
                    catch(err)
                    {
                        console.log('ManufacturerInfo: ' + 'err.name="' + err.name + '", ' + 'err.message="' + err.message);
                        dfd.reject(err);
                    }
                }
                ); 
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            console.log('DiscoveryTree: ' + 'err.name="' + err.name + '", ' + 'err.message="' + err.message);
            dfd.reject(err);
        }
    } 
    );
return dfd.promise();  
};
```

Resultado de un valor

```
<body onload="getManufacturerInfo();">
<p>Su serial es :<span id="SerialNumber"></span></p>
</body>
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola Esneyder, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender como funciona este sitio. Para que podamos ayudarte has de [edit] la pregunta y añadir tu codigo html y tu codigo javascript de lo que has intentado hasta ahora y el problema concreto que has tenido. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Mientras editas la pregunta, la pongo en espera. Un saludo

Comment: Dijiste que no se puede. Como has hecho para imprimir el valor en el input?. Muéstranos esa línea de código

Comment: no he podido imprimirlo en un input ,necesito saber si lo puedo hacer ya que intente pasar valores con ajax pero no he tenido exito

Comment: Pero la línea de código donde quieres pasarlo al input, eso necesitamos ver, ya me imagino cual es tu error, y es necesario ver ese código para confirmarte. Aprovecha  mientras este en espera.

Answer (score 2):

En el javascript cambia la propiedad innerHTML por value así:

```
document.getElementById("SerialNumber").value = deviceinfo.deviceSerialNumber;
```

y en el html cambias el span por el input así:

```
<p>Su serial es :<input type="text" id="SerialNumber"></p>
```

Saludos

Comment: Estaba revisando la propiedad value ,hice la prueba y no funciona pero muchas gracias ,de igual forma seria lo adecuado pero no lo toma

Comment: hice pruebas con la propiedad submit en vez de type text y si se genera el valor ,no entiendo que puede estar pasando